# Резиновое боковое меню

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, подскажите как правильно сделать резиновое боковое меню? Мой стиль для меню следующий:

```
.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  top: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #00bfff;
}

.sub-menu li {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid aquamarine;
  color: white;
 }

.sub-menu a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
 }
```

Т.е. я пытаюсь растянуть на всю страницу с помощью `height: 100vh`.

Но если основной контент не помещается на странице, то появляется скрол, а меню остаётся на прежнем месте.

[image: Меню осталось на месте]

В идеале боковая часть должна быть полностью закрашена цветом бокового меню.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С `absolute`:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 200px;
}

aside {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

main {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <aside>
      Sidebar
    </aside>

    <main>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus maxime, ab dolor deleniti ipsa natus placeat doloremque similique quae, harum tempora expedita obcaecati. Nihil nemo hic, in doloremque animi, aspernatur dignissimos, rem nobis voluptas eligendi perferendis deserunt delectus voluptatibus provident consequuntur soluta nisi officia architecto ad. Aut veritatis, minima cupiditate possimus distinctio, tempore et sunt cumque animi, aspernatur iste officiis dolores necessitatibus dignissimos enim vitae. Illo fuga maxime nisi a beatae aspernatur laborum voluptate doloribus necessitatibus, tenetur aliquid perspiciatis fugit earum soluta veritatis ea, accusamus ipsum porro. Ut, distinctio, quaerat. Eligendi atque blanditiis quia explicabo necessitatibus nisi reiciendis odio illo nihil quis tenetur aliquam in iusto ipsa ducimus similique doloremque dolorum maxime, libero odit nesciunt rerum reprehenderit corporis voluptatum. Ipsa ut fugiat voluptate nemo eius, accusamus quas obcaecati. Cumque beatae dolorum dolores quasi aliquid ad dicta commodi animi quaerat enim, architecto, soluta optio voluptates provident ipsum. Ea perspiciatis quis minima, omnis laboriosam et ducimus voluptas quos, quae vitae, sed expedita nam! Odit culpa eligendi repellendus cumque consequatur recusandae possimus deserunt quaerat non impedit beatae, ratione ipsum et ea vitae neque iusto praesentium architecto modi voluptate fuga delectus nisi. Quisquam, labore id voluptas totam hic cum commodi autem modi. Molestias minus vero earum quas repellendus sint ipsum esse dolorum vel error libero obcaecati explicabo, laborum ipsa necessitatibus nisi voluptatem, quod! Sint perferendis voluptatibus ducimus, placeat suscipit culpa odio iure iusto facere qui reprehenderit beatae necessitatibus illum, earum minus sit ea id neque asperiores impedit at inventore accusamus assumenda. Eveniet quaerat laboriosam eum debitis, earum dolores repellat molestiae velit reprehenderit! Atque enim beatae possimus nisi modi magnam illo dolores, officia, nemo in ipsum dolorem recusandae totam nesciunt. Magnam expedita quasi vel magni, cum veniam atque sunt porro asperiores et architecto impedit quos in delectus ratione reprehenderit natus blanditiis nobis excepturi nisi, vero tenetur. Libero deleniti quas esse soluta, amet quidem ex placeat quibusdam earum alias inventore dolores itaque velit, autem repudiandae, repellat accusantium. Ratione facilis, officia numquam aut, tenetur nesciunt quod non sit perferendis! Animi quam odit cupiditate, quibusdam, neque voluptas beatae dolor minus iusto esse. Sit voluptate magni obcaecati eligendi id eum quaerat aut exercitationem, veniam ipsam sed atque praesentium perferendis commodi non adipisci quod modi amet molestias, vel, totam optio earum rerum eveniet saepe. Dicta deleniti facilis, officia suscipit recusandae a maxime labore, molestias amet quasi blanditiis similique error tempora. Possimus repellat asperiores iusto ipsa labore error libero, non officia deserunt, nemo quo sint sequi? Voluptate, doloremque aliquid ex in cumque amet suscipit impedit corporis itaque quisquam totam reprehenderit cupiditate praesentium exercitationem iusto nisi, sit iure fugiat tenetur et recusandae est, accusantium neque mollitia! Ea libero expedita autem architecto dolores numquam, sed, eveniet quas veniam magni, alias doloribus quibusdam. Obcaecati a ullam aperiam consequuntur magni voluptas modi culpa, voluptatibus fuga error autem neque ratione repudiandae, beatae labore rerum accusantium voluptatem, dignissimos id porro fugiat dolorem laudantium natus. Accusamus, perferendis, nam. Provident eos aliquid maxime, ipsum. Odit tenetur et delectus, deserunt reprehenderit sapiente dicta quidem, porro dolores excepturi facere quibusdam illo tempora! Ullam consectetur, ipsum dolor ex a consequatur culpa! Voluptatibus ipsum, autem iste enim earum commodi quibusdam sequi similique unde maxime soluta repellendus optio voluptate quam iusto officia magni vero odit, ab voluptatem eius nam nihil harum ipsam illo. Esse doloribus, odit eius veniam magnam! Voluptatum eos, aliquid quis dolores ullam minima consectetur expedita, magnam laudantium laborum tenetur in, libero est nulla magni optio repellat blanditiis esse at ex dolor ut commodi quisquam temporibus quas. Incidunt, consequuntur odit repellendus fugiat quisquam, totam similique veniam doloribus nam facilis nostrum sint quam molestiae magni, architecto perferendis corrupti. Nulla recusandae sed deleniti qui incidunt necessitatibus minima, veniam accusantium nam, architecto quibusdam. Possimus dolore harum sapiente ipsum ab consectetur iste a voluptatibus error repudiandae similique culpa eum maxime amet at perferendis ad ratione laboriosam laborum vero consequatur cum, delectus, illum repellat. Culpa quae quasi itaque! Rem ducimus, nostrum autem, unde optio hic magnam, rerum incidunt reprehenderit quidem voluptates ipsa esse eveniet officiis. Impedit voluptates modi sunt pariatur quis, unde laborum nesciunt quibusdam minus, aut aperiam ea ipsa officia quos voluptatibus laudantium praesentium minima blanditiis ipsam officiis suscipit, esse repellendus. Voluptatum, quasi sunt maiores? Quae voluptas cum fugit illum, asperiores. Asperiores incidunt repellendus, rerum odio nemo explicabo sint natus ut similique quidem necessitatibus earum labore laborum alias vitae nostrum in atque ex deleniti inventore pariatur ab soluta. Dolore distinctio enim, error saepe quos facere doloribus quia odio possimus expedita accusamus placeat, sint quas iure perferendis numquam quis assumenda vel beatae ex adipisci repudiandae quibusdam, asperiores. Nulla molestiae eveniet eum labore quisquam itaque ducimus eligendi dolorum est, nemo laboriosam porro, earum repellendus dolor in consectetur. Nostrum at ab quas nemo? Quae, voluptatem repellat, laboriosam nam minus, est recusandae inventore, atque eveniet libero iure eos eum maiores porro obcaecati possimus optio facere itaque. Cupiditate dolores aut ex accusamus voluptatem quidem aliquid officiis, ratione quam amet totam ipsum maiores repudiandae saepe voluptatibus, minima dolorem ea obcaecati praesentium quibusdam blanditiis. Quidem placeat, enim dolores facere qui rem ratione? Neque, quod! Consectetur laboriosam totam architecto quibusdam quaerat iure debitis, itaque ducimus, sapiente, quo tempora labore. Minus et velit aut cupiditate dolor neque perferendis, incidunt recusandae nemo libero blanditiis voluptatibus ullam, nostrum similique error unde animi aliquam asperiores ut. Laboriosam, dolorum earum, ad, necessitatibus recusandae ab rerum expedita suscipit ullam, quasi voluptatem voluptas! Dolore reiciendis laboriosam minus, molestiae similique culpa magnam esse nisi quam porro iusto quibusdam blanditiis explicabo facere earum deserunt ipsam quasi ducimus repellat at, quae recusandae. Reiciendis ipsum illo rerum tempore sit minus illum quaerat error tempora possimus, incidunt fuga eaque quas optio consequatur, ea soluta asperiores praesentium. Vitae, accusamus dolore assumenda, alias voluptas dolor adipisci totam minima enim laboriosam nihil, tempora voluptate ad earum magni? Voluptatibus numquam architecto debitis modi in quibusdam, repellendus laborum consequatur obcaecati perspiciatis eum omnis. Nam commodi nihil fugit, sunt laudantium maiores facere, est itaque, ullam ratione illum veritatis! Est possimus vel laborum at asperiores quia, modi excepturi quas, rerum atque ullam ducimus temporibus consequuntur iure dolor quasi laboriosam deleniti. Odit tempore, esse!
      </p>
    </main>
  </div>
```

C `flex`:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <aside>
      Sidebar
    </aside>

    <main>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus maxime, ab dolor deleniti ipsa natus placeat doloremque similique quae, harum tempora expedita obcaecati. Nihil nemo hic, in doloremque animi, aspernatur dignissimos, rem nobis voluptas eligendi perferendis deserunt delectus voluptatibus provident consequuntur soluta nisi officia architecto ad. Aut veritatis, minima cupiditate possimus distinctio, tempore et sunt cumque animi, aspernatur iste officiis dolores necessitatibus dignissimos enim vitae. Illo fuga maxime nisi a beatae aspernatur laborum voluptate doloribus necessitatibus, tenetur aliquid perspiciatis fugit earum soluta veritatis ea, accusamus ipsum porro. Ut, distinctio, quaerat. Eligendi atque blanditiis quia explicabo necessitatibus nisi reiciendis odio illo nihil quis tenetur aliquam in iusto ipsa ducimus similique doloremque dolorum maxime, libero odit nesciunt rerum reprehenderit corporis voluptatum. Ipsa ut fugiat voluptate nemo eius, accusamus quas obcaecati. Cumque beatae dolorum dolores quasi aliquid ad dicta commodi animi quaerat enim, architecto, soluta optio voluptates provident ipsum. Ea perspiciatis quis minima, omnis laboriosam et ducimus voluptas quos, quae vitae, sed expedita nam! Odit culpa eligendi repellendus cumque consequatur recusandae possimus deserunt quaerat non impedit beatae, ratione ipsum et ea vitae neque iusto praesentium architecto modi voluptate fuga delectus nisi. Quisquam, labore id voluptas totam hic cum commodi autem modi. Molestias minus vero earum quas repellendus sint ipsum esse dolorum vel error libero obcaecati explicabo, laborum ipsa necessitatibus nisi voluptatem, quod! Sint perferendis voluptatibus ducimus, placeat suscipit culpa odio iure iusto facere qui reprehenderit beatae necessitatibus illum, earum minus sit ea id neque asperiores impedit at inventore accusamus assumenda. Eveniet quaerat laboriosam eum debitis, earum dolores repellat molestiae velit reprehenderit! Atque enim beatae possimus nisi modi magnam illo dolores, officia, nemo in ipsum dolorem recusandae totam nesciunt. Magnam expedita quasi vel magni, cum veniam atque sunt porro asperiores et architecto impedit quos in delectus ratione reprehenderit natus blanditiis nobis excepturi nisi, vero tenetur. Libero deleniti quas esse soluta, amet quidem ex placeat quibusdam earum alias inventore dolores itaque velit, autem repudiandae, repellat accusantium. Ratione facilis, officia numquam aut, tenetur nesciunt quod non sit perferendis! Animi quam odit cupiditate, quibusdam, neque voluptas beatae dolor minus iusto esse. Sit voluptate magni obcaecati eligendi id eum quaerat aut exercitationem, veniam ipsam sed atque praesentium perferendis commodi non adipisci quod modi amet molestias, vel, totam optio earum rerum eveniet saepe. Dicta deleniti facilis, officia suscipit recusandae a maxime labore, molestias amet quasi blanditiis similique error tempora. Possimus repellat asperiores iusto ipsa labore error libero, non officia deserunt, nemo quo sint sequi? Voluptate, doloremque aliquid ex in cumque amet suscipit impedit corporis itaque quisquam totam reprehenderit cupiditate praesentium exercitationem iusto nisi, sit iure fugiat tenetur et recusandae est, accusantium neque mollitia! Ea libero expedita autem architecto dolores numquam, sed, eveniet quas veniam magni, alias doloribus quibusdam. Obcaecati a ullam aperiam consequuntur magni voluptas modi culpa, voluptatibus fuga error autem neque ratione repudiandae, beatae labore rerum accusantium voluptatem, dignissimos id porro fugiat dolorem laudantium natus. Accusamus, perferendis, nam. Provident eos aliquid maxime, ipsum. Odit tenetur et delectus, deserunt reprehenderit sapiente dicta quidem, porro dolores excepturi facere quibusdam illo tempora! Ullam consectetur, ipsum dolor ex a consequatur culpa! Voluptatibus ipsum, autem iste enim earum commodi quibusdam sequi similique unde maxime soluta repellendus optio voluptate quam iusto officia magni vero odit, ab voluptatem eius nam nihil harum ipsam illo. Esse doloribus, odit eius veniam magnam! Voluptatum eos, aliquid quis dolores ullam minima consectetur expedita, magnam laudantium laborum tenetur in, libero est nulla magni optio repellat blanditiis esse at ex dolor ut commodi quisquam temporibus quas. Incidunt, consequuntur odit repellendus fugiat quisquam, totam similique veniam doloribus nam facilis nostrum sint quam molestiae magni, architecto perferendis corrupti. Nulla recusandae sed deleniti qui incidunt necessitatibus minima, veniam accusantium nam, architecto quibusdam. Possimus dolore harum sapiente ipsum ab consectetur iste a voluptatibus error repudiandae similique culpa eum maxime amet at perferendis ad ratione laboriosam laborum vero consequatur cum, delectus, illum repellat. Culpa quae quasi itaque! Rem ducimus, nostrum autem, unde optio hic magnam, rerum incidunt reprehenderit quidem voluptates ipsa esse eveniet officiis. Impedit voluptates modi sunt pariatur quis, unde laborum nesciunt quibusdam minus, aut aperiam ea ipsa officia quos voluptatibus laudantium praesentium minima blanditiis ipsam officiis suscipit, esse repellendus. Voluptatum, quasi sunt maiores? Quae voluptas cum fugit illum, asperiores. Asperiores incidunt repellendus, rerum odio nemo explicabo sint natus ut similique quidem necessitatibus earum labore laborum alias vitae nostrum in atque ex deleniti inventore pariatur ab soluta. Dolore distinctio enim, error saepe quos facere doloribus quia odio possimus expedita accusamus placeat, sint quas iure perferendis numquam quis assumenda vel beatae ex adipisci repudiandae quibusdam, asperiores. Nulla molestiae eveniet eum labore quisquam itaque ducimus eligendi dolorum est, nemo laboriosam porro, earum repellendus dolor in consectetur. Nostrum at ab quas nemo? Quae, voluptatem repellat, laboriosam nam minus, est recusandae inventore, atque eveniet libero iure eos eum maiores porro obcaecati possimus optio facere itaque. Cupiditate dolores aut ex accusamus voluptatem quidem aliquid officiis, ratione quam amet totam ipsum maiores repudiandae saepe voluptatibus, minima dolorem ea obcaecati praesentium quibusdam blanditiis. Quidem placeat, enim dolores facere qui rem ratione? Neque, quod! Consectetur laboriosam totam architecto quibusdam quaerat iure debitis, itaque ducimus, sapiente, quo tempora labore. Minus et velit aut cupiditate dolor neque perferendis, incidunt recusandae nemo libero blanditiis voluptatibus ullam, nostrum similique error unde animi aliquam asperiores ut. Laboriosam, dolorum earum, ad, necessitatibus recusandae ab rerum expedita suscipit ullam, quasi voluptatem voluptas! Dolore reiciendis laboriosam minus, molestiae similique culpa magnam esse nisi quam porro iusto quibusdam blanditiis explicabo facere earum deserunt ipsam quasi ducimus repellat at, quae recusandae. Reiciendis ipsum illo rerum tempore sit minus illum quaerat error tempora possimus, incidunt fuga eaque quas optio consequatur, ea soluta asperiores praesentium. Vitae, accusamus dolore assumenda, alias voluptas dolor adipisci totam minima enim laboriosam nihil, tempora voluptate ad earum magni? Voluptatibus numquam architecto debitis modi in quibusdam, repellendus laborum consequatur obcaecati perspiciatis eum omnis. Nam commodi nihil fugit, sunt laudantium maiores facere, est itaque, ullam ratione illum veritatis! Est possimus vel laborum at asperiores quia, modi excepturi quas, rerum atque ullam ducimus temporibus consequuntur iure dolor quasi laboriosam deleniti. Odit tempore, esse!
      </p>
    </main>
  </div>
```

С `table`:

```css
aside {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: table-cell;
}

main {
  width: auto;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <aside>
      Sidebar
    </aside>

    <main>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus maxime, ab dolor deleniti ipsa natus placeat doloremque similique quae, harum tempora expedita obcaecati. Nihil nemo hic, in doloremque animi, aspernatur dignissimos, rem nobis voluptas eligendi perferendis deserunt delectus voluptatibus provident consequuntur soluta nisi officia architecto ad. Aut veritatis, minima cupiditate possimus distinctio, tempore et sunt cumque animi, aspernatur iste officiis dolores necessitatibus dignissimos enim vitae. Illo fuga maxime nisi a beatae aspernatur laborum voluptate doloribus necessitatibus, tenetur aliquid perspiciatis fugit earum soluta veritatis ea, accusamus ipsum porro. Ut, distinctio, quaerat. Eligendi atque blanditiis quia explicabo necessitatibus nisi reiciendis odio illo nihil quis tenetur aliquam in iusto ipsa ducimus similique doloremque dolorum maxime, libero odit nesciunt rerum reprehenderit corporis voluptatum. Ipsa ut fugiat voluptate nemo eius, accusamus quas obcaecati. Cumque beatae dolorum dolores quasi aliquid ad dicta commodi animi quaerat enim, architecto, soluta optio voluptates provident ipsum. Ea perspiciatis quis minima, omnis laboriosam et ducimus voluptas quos, quae vitae, sed expedita nam! Odit culpa eligendi repellendus cumque consequatur recusandae possimus deserunt quaerat non impedit beatae, ratione ipsum et ea vitae neque iusto praesentium architecto modi voluptate fuga delectus nisi. Quisquam, labore id voluptas totam hic cum commodi autem modi. Molestias minus vero earum quas repellendus sint ipsum esse dolorum vel error libero obcaecati explicabo, laborum ipsa necessitatibus nisi voluptatem, quod! Sint perferendis voluptatibus ducimus, placeat suscipit culpa odio iure iusto facere qui reprehenderit beatae necessitatibus illum, earum minus sit ea id neque asperiores impedit at inventore accusamus assumenda. Eveniet quaerat laboriosam eum debitis, earum dolores repellat molestiae velit reprehenderit! Atque enim beatae possimus nisi modi magnam illo dolores, officia, nemo in ipsum dolorem recusandae totam nesciunt. Magnam expedita quasi vel magni, cum veniam atque sunt porro asperiores et architecto impedit quos in delectus ratione reprehenderit natus blanditiis nobis excepturi nisi, vero tenetur. Libero deleniti quas esse soluta, amet quidem ex placeat quibusdam earum alias inventore dolores itaque velit, autem repudiandae, repellat accusantium. Ratione facilis, officia numquam aut, tenetur nesciunt quod non sit perferendis! Animi quam odit cupiditate, quibusdam, neque voluptas beatae dolor minus iusto esse. Sit voluptate magni obcaecati eligendi id eum quaerat aut exercitationem, veniam ipsam sed atque praesentium perferendis commodi non adipisci quod modi amet molestias, vel, totam optio earum rerum eveniet saepe. Dicta deleniti facilis, officia suscipit recusandae a maxime labore, molestias amet quasi blanditiis similique error tempora. Possimus repellat asperiores iusto ipsa labore error libero, non officia deserunt, nemo quo sint sequi? Voluptate, doloremque aliquid ex in cumque amet suscipit impedit corporis itaque quisquam totam reprehenderit cupiditate praesentium exercitationem iusto nisi, sit iure fugiat tenetur et recusandae est, accusantium neque mollitia! Ea libero expedita autem architecto dolores numquam, sed, eveniet quas veniam magni, alias doloribus quibusdam. Obcaecati a ullam aperiam consequuntur magni voluptas modi culpa, voluptatibus fuga error autem neque ratione repudiandae, beatae labore rerum accusantium voluptatem, dignissimos id porro fugiat dolorem laudantium natus. Accusamus, perferendis, nam. Provident eos aliquid maxime, ipsum. Odit tenetur et delectus, deserunt reprehenderit sapiente dicta quidem, porro dolores excepturi facere quibusdam illo tempora! Ullam consectetur, ipsum dolor ex a consequatur culpa! Voluptatibus ipsum, autem iste enim earum commodi quibusdam sequi similique unde maxime soluta repellendus optio voluptate quam iusto officia magni vero odit, ab voluptatem eius nam nihil harum ipsam illo. Esse doloribus, odit eius veniam magnam! Voluptatum eos, aliquid quis dolores ullam minima consectetur expedita, magnam laudantium laborum tenetur in, libero est nulla magni optio repellat blanditiis esse at ex dolor ut commodi quisquam temporibus quas. Incidunt, consequuntur odit repellendus fugiat quisquam, totam similique veniam doloribus nam facilis nostrum sint quam molestiae magni, architecto perferendis corrupti. Nulla recusandae sed deleniti qui incidunt necessitatibus minima, veniam accusantium nam, architecto quibusdam. Possimus dolore harum sapiente ipsum ab consectetur iste a voluptatibus error repudiandae similique culpa eum maxime amet at perferendis ad ratione laboriosam laborum vero consequatur cum, delectus, illum repellat. Culpa quae quasi itaque! Rem ducimus, nostrum autem, unde optio hic magnam, rerum incidunt reprehenderit quidem voluptates ipsa esse eveniet officiis. Impedit voluptates modi sunt pariatur quis, unde laborum nesciunt quibusdam minus, aut aperiam ea ipsa officia quos voluptatibus laudantium praesentium minima blanditiis ipsam officiis suscipit, esse repellendus. Voluptatum, quasi sunt maiores? Quae voluptas cum fugit illum, asperiores. Asperiores incidunt repellendus, rerum odio nemo explicabo sint natus ut similique quidem necessitatibus earum labore laborum alias vitae nostrum in atque ex deleniti inventore pariatur ab soluta. Dolore distinctio enim, error saepe quos facere doloribus quia odio possimus expedita accusamus placeat, sint quas iure perferendis numquam quis assumenda vel beatae ex adipisci repudiandae quibusdam, asperiores. Nulla molestiae eveniet eum labore quisquam itaque ducimus eligendi dolorum est, nemo laboriosam porro, earum repellendus dolor in consectetur. Nostrum at ab quas nemo? Quae, voluptatem repellat, laboriosam nam minus, est recusandae inventore, atque eveniet libero iure eos eum maiores porro obcaecati possimus optio facere itaque. Cupiditate dolores aut ex accusamus voluptatem quidem aliquid officiis, ratione quam amet totam ipsum maiores repudiandae saepe voluptatibus, minima dolorem ea obcaecati praesentium quibusdam blanditiis. Quidem placeat, enim dolores facere qui rem ratione? Neque, quod! Consectetur laboriosam totam architecto quibusdam quaerat iure debitis, itaque ducimus, sapiente, quo tempora labore. Minus et velit aut cupiditate dolor neque perferendis, incidunt recusandae nemo libero blanditiis voluptatibus ullam, nostrum similique error unde animi aliquam asperiores ut. Laboriosam, dolorum earum, ad, necessitatibus recusandae ab rerum expedita suscipit ullam, quasi voluptatem voluptas! Dolore reiciendis laboriosam minus, molestiae similique culpa magnam esse nisi quam porro iusto quibusdam blanditiis explicabo facere earum deserunt ipsam quasi ducimus repellat at, quae recusandae. Reiciendis ipsum illo rerum tempore sit minus illum quaerat error tempora possimus, incidunt fuga eaque quas optio consequatur, ea soluta asperiores praesentium. Vitae, accusamus dolore assumenda, alias voluptas dolor adipisci totam minima enim laboriosam nihil, tempora voluptate ad earum magni? Voluptatibus numquam architecto debitis modi in quibusdam, repellendus laborum consequatur obcaecati perspiciatis eum omnis. Nam commodi nihil fugit, sunt laudantium maiores facere, est itaque, ullam ratione illum veritatis! Est possimus vel laborum at asperiores quia, modi excepturi quas, rerum atque ullam ducimus temporibus consequuntur iure dolor quasi laboriosam deleniti. Odit tempore, esse!
      </p>
    </main>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Вам подойдет флексбокс-контейнер с обычными настройками. Не забудьте добавить минимальную высоту для левого блока.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.hidden').removeAttribute('hidden');
  
  this.setAttribute('hidden', true);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container__left {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.container__right {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Expand main content</button>

<div class=container>
  <div class=container__left>
    اللا يتسنّى بريطانيا، بل به،, مدن قتيل، يتمكن الإمتعاض كل. عن قام أساسي اليميني, أمام تعداد أطراف وصل كل. تطوير تكاليف استطاعوا الا قد, جُل ابتدعها الإمتعاض هو. فقد إذ وشعار لمحاكم.
  </div>
  <div class=container__right>
    المتّبعة ان قام. دول أعمال واستمرت ثم. وصل العالم الأمريكي أن, كلّ كل النفط الإتحاد. بحث كل الأخذ أطراف المشترك, و المدن العالم وقد.

اللا يتسنّى بريطانيا، بل به،, مدن قتيل، يتمكن الإمتعاض كل. عن قام أساسي اليميني, أمام تعداد أطراف وصل كل. تطوير تكاليف استطاعوا الا قد, جُل ابتدعها الإمتعاض هو. فقد إذ وشعار لمحاكم.

اليها لإنعدام أضف إذ, دخول تكتيكاً ٣٠ بحق. بال ان وبغطاء وبالرغم للسيطرة. إذ يتم أعمال وبالرغم الخارجية, هو اعتداء واعتلاء غير, كل للمجهود المزيفة الا. هامش غينيا أم مدن, لم ووصف إحكام اليابانية لان. جعل و الأخذ المدن ديسمبر. عدد هو معقل الثالث, وانهاء الأوربيين قام ما.
    <div class="hidden" hidden>

    المتّبعة ان قام. دول أعمال واستمرت ثم. وصل العالم الأمريكي أن, كلّ كل النفط الإتحاد. بحث كل الأخذ أطراف المشترك, و المدن العالم وقد.

اللا يتسنّى بريطانيا، بل به،, مدن قتيل، يتمكن الإمتعاض كل. عن قام أساسي اليميني, أمام تعداد أطراف وصل كل. تطوير تكاليف استطاعوا الا قد, جُل ابتدعها الإمتعاض هو. فقد إذ وشعار لمحاكم.

اليها لإنعدام أضف إذ, دخول تكتيكاً ٣٠ بحق. بال ان وبغطاء وبالرغم للسيطرة. إذ يتم أعمال وبالرغم الخارجية, هو اعتداء واعتلاء غير, كل للمجهود المزيفة الا. هامش غينيا أم مدن, لم ووصف إحكام اليابانية لان. جعل و الأخذ المدن ديسمبر. عدد هو معقل الثالث, وانهاء الأوربيين قام ما.

    المتّبعة ان قام. دول أعمال واستمرت ثم. وصل العالم الأمريكي أن, كلّ كل النفط الإتحاد. بحث كل الأخذ أطراف المشترك, و المدن العالم وقد.

اللا يتسنّى بريطانيا، بل به،, مدن قتيل، يتمكن الإمتعاض كل. عن قام أساسي اليميني, أمام تعداد أطراف وصل كل. تطوير تكاليف استطاعوا الا قد, جُل ابتدعها الإمتعاض هو. فقد إذ وشعار لمحاكم.

اليها لإنعدام أضف إذ, دخول تكتيكاً ٣٠ بحق. بال ان وبغطاء وبالرغم للسيطرة. إذ يتم أعمال وبالرغم الخارجية, هو اعتداء واعتلاء غير, كل للمجهود المزيفة الا. هامش غينيا أم مدن, لم ووصف إحكام اليابانية لان. جعل و الأخذ المدن ديسمبر. عدد هو معقل الثالث, وانهاء الأوربيين قام ما.

    المتّبعة ان قام. دول أعمال واستمرت ثم. وصل العالم الأمريكي أن, كلّ كل النفط الإتحاد. بحث كل الأخذ أطراف المشترك, و المدن العالم وقد.

اللا يتسنّى بريطانيا، بل به،, مدن قتيل، يتمكن الإمتعاض كل. عن قام أساسي اليميني, أمام تعداد أطراف وصل كل. تطوير تكاليف استطاعوا الا قد, جُل ابتدعها الإمتعاض هو. فقد إذ وشعار لمحاكم.

اليها لإنعدام أضف إذ, دخول تكتيكاً ٣٠ بحق. بال ان وبغطاء وبالرغم للسيطرة. إذ يتم أعمال وبالرغم الخارجية, هو اعتداء واعتلاء غير, كل للمجهود المزيفة الا. هامش غينيا أم مدن, لم ووصف إحكام اليابانية لان. جعل و الأخذ المدن ديسمبر. عدد هو معقل الثالث, وانهاء الأوربيين قام ما.

    المتّبعة ان قام. دول أعمال واستمرت ثم. وصل العالم الأمريكي أن, كلّ كل النفط الإتحاد. بحث كل الأخذ أطراف المشترك, و المدن العالم وقد.

اللا يتسنّى بريطانيا، بل به،, مدن قتيل، يتمكن الإمتعاض كل. عن قام أساسي اليميني, أمام تعداد أطراف وصل كل. تطوير تكاليف استطاعوا الا قد, جُل ابتدعها الإمتعاض هو. فقد إذ وشعار لمحاكم.

اليها لإنعدام أضف إذ, دخول تكتيكاً ٣٠ بحق. بال ان وبغطاء وبالرغم للسيطرة. إذ يتم أعمال وبالرغم الخارجية, هو اعتداء واعتلاء غير, كل للمجهود المزيفة الا. هامش غينيا أم مدن, لم ووصف إحكام اليابانية لان. جعل و الأخذ المدن ديسمبر. عدد هو معقل الثالث, وانهاء الأوربيين قام ما.

    المتّبعة ان قام. دول أعمال واستمرت ثم. وصل العالم الأمريكي أن, كلّ كل النفط الإتحاد. بحث كل الأخذ أطراف المشترك, و المدن العالم وقد.

اللا يتسنّى بريطانيا، بل به،, مدن قتيل، يتمكن الإمتعاض كل. عن قام أساسي اليميني, أمام تعداد أطراف وصل كل. تطوير تكاليف استطاعوا الا قد, جُل ابتدعها الإمتعاض هو. فقد إذ وشعار لمحاكم.

اليها لإنعدام أضف إذ, دخول تكتيكاً ٣٠ بحق. بال ان وبغطاء وبالرغم للسيطرة. إذ يتم أعمال وبالرغم الخارجية, هو اعتداء واعتلاء غير, كل للمجهود المزيفة الا. هامش غينيا أم مدن, لم ووصف إحكام اليابانية لان. جعل و الأخذ المدن ديسمبر. عدد هو معقل الثالث, وانهاء الأوربيين قام ما.

    المتّبعة ان قام. دول أعمال واستمرت ثم. وصل العالم الأمريكي أن, كلّ كل النفط الإتحاد. بحث كل الأخذ أطراف المشترك, و المدن العالم وقد.

اللا يتسنّى بريطانيا، بل به،, مدن قتيل، يتمكن الإمتعاض كل. عن قام أساسي اليميني, أمام تعداد أطراف وصل كل. تطوير تكاليف استطاعوا الا قد, جُل ابتدعها الإمتعاض هو. فقد إذ وشعار لمحاكم.

اليها لإنعدام أضف إذ, دخول تكتيكاً ٣٠ بحق. بال ان وبغطاء وبالرغم للسيطرة. إذ يتم أعمال وبالرغم الخارجية, هو اعتداء واعتلاء غير, كل للمجهود المزيفة الا. هامش غينيا أم مدن, لم ووصف إحكام اليابانية لان. جعل و الأخذ المدن ديسمبر. عدد هو معقل الثالث, وانهاء الأوربيين قام ما.

    المتّبعة ان قام. دول أعمال واستمرت ثم. وصل العالم الأمريكي أن, كلّ كل النفط الإتحاد. بحث كل الأخذ أطراف المشترك, و المدن العالم وقد.

اللا يتسنّى بريطانيا، بل به،, مدن قتيل، يتمكن الإمتعاض كل. عن قام أساسي اليميني, أمام تعداد أطراف وصل كل. تطوير تكاليف استطاعوا الا قد, جُل ابتدعها الإمتعاض هو. فقد إذ وشعار لمحاكم.

اليها لإنعدام أضف إذ, دخول تكتيكاً ٣٠ بحق. بال ان وبغطاء وبالرغم للسيطرة. إذ يتم أعمال وبالرغم الخارجية, هو اعتداء واعتلاء غير, كل للمجهود المزيفة الا. هامش غينيا أم مدن, لم ووصف إحكام اليابانية لان. جعل و الأخذ المدن ديسمبر. عدد هو معقل الثالث, وانهاء الأوربيين قام ما.

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```